# In C#, is boxing and unboxing involved when casting long to ulong and vice versa?

Tags: c#, endianness, boxing

I know that boxing then unboxing is computationally expensive, and it happens when casting a value type to object or other reference type then back to value type. However, does this happen when I'm casting long to ulong or vice versa.

I have following code:

```
ulong number = (ulong)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((long)BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes));
```

My understanding is, since both long and ulong are value type, casting between them will not have any boxing or unboxing involved.

I just want to be sure, does the code above have boxing and unboxing involved?

Comment: short answer: no.

Comment: To reiterate: No. Boxing and unboxing have to do with taking instances of _value types_ (like `int`, `long`, `ulong`, `DateTime`, etc.) and putting them into a _box_ that is allocated like any other _reference type_ instance and can be treated like any other reference type subclass of `System.Object` (aka `object`). Boxing and unboxing are not that computationally expensive. The expense is in the allocation of an object and the eventual garbage collection of that object. Generally, boxed quantities live for a short time, it feels wasteful, like single use plastic items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ulong` and `long` are both value types.  Boxing only occurs if you convert a value type to a reference type.

The source code for NetworkToHostOrder is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/IPAddress.cs,516).  As you can see, no boxing occurs there either; it's just bit operations.

Some weirdness may occur if you use a checked conversion from `ulong` to `long` that is outside of the range of the `long`, because an exception object will be created.  But you probably have larger problems at that point.

Comment: "Boxing only occurs if you convert a value type to a reference type." You can define any custom `implicit` or `explicit` operator to do whatever you want. But the `ulong` to `long` conversion is defined without boxing, yes.

Comment: Yes, you can define an operator that boxes, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumptions.

These are both value types and both are 8 bytes each.  Since you are changing from value type to another value type, it's neither.  When you convert from one to the other, you are just changing the bit that controls the sign of the number--meaning if it's a positive or negative number.

So this is not boxing nor unboxing.  This is called explicit type casting, when you convert from long to ulong, or vice versa.

> What is boxing? Boxing is the process of converting a value type to
> the object type or any interface type implemented by this value type.
> Boxing is implicit.
>
> What is Unboxing? Unboxing is the reverse of boxing. It is the process
> of converting a reference type to value type. Unboxing extract the
> value from the reference type and assign it to a value type.
>
> C# Explicit Type Conversion (Cast) Explicit conversion is required
> when the data cannot convert from one simple-type to another
> automatically by the compiler or when conversion may change the value
> by producing an incorrect result due to the possible loss of data
> (narrowing conversions). To prevent a compilation error in cases where
> information may be lost due to an implicit conversion between types,
> the compiler requires you to use a cast operator to perform the type
> conversion. When using explicit conversion, you deliberately force the
> compiler to convert the value even though there is a loss of
> information. Keep in mind that all casts are potentially unsafe.
>
> C# Implicit Type Conversion (Hidden) If one type is converted into
> another type automatically by the CLR, it’s called implicit type
> conversion. No special casting syntax is required, and no data is lost
> during implicit conversion. Despite the fact that loss of precision
> may occur during the conversion process, which is allowed and never
> results in a run-time exception by the compiler, a widening primitive
> conversion always succeeds, where conversion is done from a smaller to
> a bigger data type without any risk of data being lost at all—for
> instance, casting an int to a double.

https://codebuns.com/csharp-basics/type-conversion/